# How to create a new session in Django?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to create a new session in Django? For instance I have a URL that is always going to be opened in a new tab and I would like a new session to get created whenever someone visits that URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you would like to delete the previous session cookie? In which case:

To clear the session data as well as the cookie:

```
request.session.flush()
```

To clear the session data but keep the same cookie just use the dict.clear():

```
request.session.clear()
```

For details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: No, I would like to create a new session cookie so it would appear as if 2 different sessions were browsing my site.

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically need 2 cookies? You can code in some logic and simulate 2 sessions with 1 session.

Comment: Writing code to simulate 2 sessions means that there could be scenarios where the illusion fails. Far better to have 2 separate sessions so the illusion never breaks.

Comment: So as you probably know, django by default stores sessions with a "sessionid" cookie. If you want to have 2 sessions you run into the problem of saving a second "sessionid" cookie. Best way I can think of is creating maybe a "sessionid_2" cookie, temporarily delete the "sessionid" cookie to force django to create a new session for you. And then edit the "sessionid" cookie each time before you send a request from each respective URL(saving the other session in "sessionid_2"). This would imply that each of your two instances knows which sessionid they correspond to.